# Swipe down do refresh on regular View in react native app

Tags: javascript, react-native, swiperefreshlayout

Is there a way to do a swipe down to refresh in react native on a regular view without using something like a FlatList or ScrollView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in solution for doing this. We usually want some kind of feedback for the user, thus the regular `pull to refresh` action is a suitable choice and this obviously only works in some kind of `scrollable container`.

However, if we still do not want to use a `ScrollView` for this purpose, then we could listen to touch gestures and react after a certain treshold as follows.

```js
const SomeRefreshableNonScrollableComponent = (props) => {
   const y = useRef()

   function onRefresh() {
        // refresh or whatever
   }

   return (
    <View
      style={{flex :1}}
      onTouchStart={e=> y.current = e.nativeEvent.pageY}
      onTouchEnd={e => {
        // some threshold. add whatever suits you
        if (y.current - e.nativeEvent.pageY < 40) {
          onRefresh()
        }
      }}>

     ...

    </View>
  )
}
```

**Edit:** As an answer to the comments.

We can implement a pull down to refresh mechanism for a `FlatList` that is nested inside a not scrollable `ScrollView` as follows.

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
  const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {

    if (refresh) {
      console.log("Refresh my inner data on pull")
    }
  }, [refresh])

  return (
    <ScrollView scrollEnabled={false} nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
      <FlatList refreshing={refresh} onRefresh={() => setRefresh(true)} data={data} renderItem={({item}) => {
        return <Text>Hello world</Text>
      }} />
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

Notice that you must reset your `refresh` state back to `false` once your refresh action is done, e.g. if an API call returns its data. Otherwise, the Flatlist will keep showing the refresh indicator.

Comment: @davidschloz Ok, now that I think of it is there a way to do it with a ScrollView but to disable the parent Scroll View and enable it in the nested FlatList ? I have an app like this
https://prnt.sc/aN3ASlrmiHuf , the component marked red is a FlatList and the whole screen is nested in a regular View, can it be changed instead to A ScrollView with disabled scrolling but still being able to scroll the FlatList ?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. See my updated answer.